# What is better coding for turning list into sequence without curly brackets?

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting, printing

There are less satisfying Q/A for what I am asking but none that actually answer the question. Suppose one has

```
a=1; b={2,3};
```

And one wants to print a sequence of numbers a, b, c without curly brackets. Then if one prints

```
Print[a,", ",b]
```

One obtains

1, {2,3}

One solution to this is to print

```
Print[a,", ",b[[1]],", ",b[[2]]]
```

Then one obtains

1, 2, 3

What is going on is that the only way to get rid of the curly brackets in a list is to extract single values from that list. So that single value extraction by parts is a solution to my question but not an efficient one for a longer list like

```
 b={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}
```

So now the question. Is their a more efficient way to print a longer list without the curly brackets?

Comment: `Print @@ Riffle[Prepend[b, a], ", "]` or `Print[Fold[# <> ", " <> ToString[#2] &, ToString[a], b]]`?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Riffle works fine, thanks.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, also works fine.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Would you write `Print @@ Riffle[Prepend[b, a], ", "]` as an answer, please?

Comment: @MarcoB Write as an answer, please.

Comment: @Carl Converted as suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Converting a comment into an answer</sup>

One way would be

```
Print @@ Riffle[Prepend[b, a], ", "]
```

For example,

```
a = 1;
b = {2, 3};
Print @@ Riffle[Prepend[b, a], ", "]
```

> `1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment into answer as suggested:

```
a = 1; b = {2, 3};
Print[a, ", ", Sequence @@ Riffle[b, ", "]]

(* Out: 1, 2, 3 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
Row[Flatten @ {a, b}, ","]
```

> [image]

Comment: Wow! (+1) Even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are printing the `InputForm` of whatever expression you give to `Print`. So if you want to print the `String` `"1, 2, 3"` then you will need to construct that `String` to print.

The following does what you need (and works for any number of `List`s of elements):

```
a = {1};
b = {2, 3};

str = StringRiffle[Join[a, b], ", "]
```

Yields

```
1, 2, 3
```

And if you want to `Print` this (which may not be the right tool in the first place depending on what you want to do), then you can just `Print[ str ]` and it will do what you want.

The idea is to join the lists together and then separate them by commas as a `String`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice use of `StringRiffle` (+1)! Note, however, that `a` was not a list in the original question.

Comment: A worthy thing to note is that `StringRiffle` uses `TextString` to convert objects to `String`s, so there may be unexpected conversions (e.g. `TextString[Sqrt[2]]` gives `"1.41421"`)

Comment: @enano9314 Actually, `Print @@ Riffle[Prepend[b, a], ", "]` works better because the output is numeric or string, whereas Print[StringRiffle[Join[a, b], ", "]] interprets the numbers as strings and actually modifies the output type. For example, `Anderson-Darling, 0.991363`  becomes `Anderson-Darling, 0.99136287` using StringRiffle.  In the first case, 0.991363 still means 0.991362865780819\` but is a string in the second case.

Comment: Nice catch @MarcoB and @Carl these are certainly good points, and I should have been more careful. If we really just want this `Print`ed and not as an actual string, then yes, the `Riffle`/`Prepend` method is better here.

Nice catch(es)!